# Java hashmap edits existing entry when putting a new entry

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to make a hashmap to add weights to specific items. But once I start adding more items to it, it also updates the existing items.

The HashMap maps a PathMaterial to a Double

Here is my PathMaterial Class:

```
package com.test;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class PathMaterial {
    public enum Material {
        AIR,
        STONE,
        GRASS,
        DIRT;

        int getId() {
            return this.ordinal();
        }
    }

    public Material mat;
    public byte data;

    public PathMaterial(Material mat, byte data) {
        this.mat = mat;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof PathMaterial)) {
            return false;
        }
        PathMaterial other = (PathMaterial) obj;

        return mat == other.mat && data == other.data;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Integer.parseInt(
                new DecimalFormat("000").format(mat.getId()) + "" + new DecimalFormat("00").format((int) data));
    }
}
```

And here is the code i'm using for the weights and stuff:

```
package com.test;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    private HashMap<PathMaterial, Double> weightedBlocks;
    int totalWeight;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        weightedBlocks = new HashMap<>();
        totalWeight = 0;

        addBlock(PathMaterial.Material.DIRT, 1, (byte)1);
        addBlock(PathMaterial.Material.STONE, 1, (byte)1);
        addBlock(PathMaterial.Material.STONE, 1, (byte)2);

        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    private void denormalizeWeights() {
        double previous = 0;
        for (Map.Entry pair : weightedBlocks.entrySet()) {
            weightedBlocks.put((PathMaterial) pair.getKey(),
                               (double) pair.getValue() - previous);
            previous = (double) pair.getValue();
        }

        for (Map.Entry pair : weightedBlocks.entrySet()) {
            weightedBlocks.put((PathMaterial) pair.getKey(),
                               (double) pair.getValue() * totalWeight);
        }
    }

    private void normalizeWeights() {
        for (Map.Entry pair : weightedBlocks.entrySet()) {
            weightedBlocks.put((PathMaterial) pair.getKey(),
                               (double) pair.getValue() / totalWeight);
        }

        double previous = 0;
        for (Map.Entry pair : weightedBlocks.entrySet()) {
            weightedBlocks.put((PathMaterial) pair.getKey(),
                               (double) pair.getValue() + previous);
            previous = (double) pair.getValue();
        }
    }

    public void addBlock(final PathMaterial.Material mat, double weight, byte data) {
        denormalizeWeights();
        weightedBlocks.put(new PathMaterial(mat, data), weight);
        //        weightedBlocks.put(mat, weight);
        totalWeight = getTotalWeight();
        normalizeWeights();
    }

    private int getTotalWeight() {
        int weight = 0;
        for (double d : weightedBlocks.values()) {
            weight += d;
        }
        return weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                "PathBuilder with name '" + "test" + "'\nRadius: " + 3 + "\nWeightmap:");
        denormalizeWeights();
        for (Map.Entry pair : weightedBlocks.entrySet()) {
            PathMaterial mat = (PathMaterial) pair.getKey();
            String matName = mat.mat.name() + ":" + mat.data;
            String percentage = new DecimalFormat("00.0").format(((double) pair.getValue()) / totalWeight * 100);
            sb.append("\n-" + matName + " [" + percentage + "%]");
        }
        normalizeWeights();

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

In my test i add 3 PathMaterials in this order:
PathMaterial(DIRT, 1) with a weight of 1
PathMaterial(STONE, 1) with a weight of 1
PathMaterial(STONE, 2) with a weight of 1
But after adding the 3rd item, the weight of PathMaterial(DIRT, 1) is 2
The weight of this item is changed with the HashMap#put call in the addBlock method (i checked with a debugger and the weight was right before the put call and was wrong after the put call)

I have also uploaded this project [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sdh33bw2Il7xiqsnw4NE_0TbfIl2v8Gf)

Comment: Why do you mean by "updates existing items" ? Show in the question how you know this.  A trick is to reduce your code to the smallest [mcve] so it is easy to see what is going on. You can also debug your code with simple log or print lines to see what it is doing when updating entries, etc.

Comment: ah yes i'll add that to the question

Comment: You do realize you're modifying the whole map every time you add an item, don't you?

Comment: Yes, the way i use this map is as follows: i generate a random double (between 0 and 1) then i loop through the map until i find an entry with a weight higher than my random number and i'll use that element

Comment: Observation :  your toString is modifying the map? This is bad design.

Comment: The HashMap.entrySet() documentation says: "If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation, or through the setValue operation on a map entry returned by the iterator) the results of the iteration are undefined." In other words, your normalizeWeights and denormalizeWeights methods are dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you comment out normalize and denomalize part it won't update anything after put call. You mess up references in those methods so if you put a debug point on weightedBlocks.put(new PathMaterial(mat, data), weight); and evaluate weightedBlocks couple of time in a row you'll see that the reference to double value is changed every time you do evaluate.

[image: First Call]
This is just Alt+F8 and evaluate of map after 3rd call to addBlock(). I'm holding debug point on #put all the time.
[image: Second Call]
Second time I press evaluate while still holding on the same line you can see references to Double change.

If I comment out the code in normalize and denormalize it gives me always same references.

So you have to be clear about what you wan't in those function to happen and maybe I can help. From this point it looks like update and some of your comments point out you want to add new items which is not possible in a way you wrote it.

Because I'm not clear 100% about what you want I need more details and I probably didn't get it right but do feel free to comment on this.

Comment: To give more details about why does #put change the element when debugging: Debugger runs toString() on Main class and toString() as said before changes the map so that's why you see different values when debugging.

Comment: I think your answer is spot on. One more observation, the `[de]normalizeWeights` methods change the values of each element according to values in previous iterations. But after a `put`, you've got another value that might affect values coming after it in an iteration. Also this is a HashMap, so iteration order is unpredictable and may change when you add a new element. This means that a denormalize followed by a normalize is not guaranteed to bring back the original values.

Comment: I changed my toString method to not use normalizeWeights and deNormalizeWeights and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Your code will update existing item because nowhere you restricted the code while updating the item. (or) nowhere you reinitializing the variable.

Comment: I'm not updating any item, i'm only adding new items

Comment: Every time when you add the new item,  you are iterating all items from the weightedBlocks, so it will update the existing item, which already stored in this weightedBlocks . There should be some restriction.

Comment: the normalizeWeights and denormalizeWeights work as intended. It's after the HashMap.put in addBlock method (where i add a new block) that the weight of another element gets changed

Comment: @chrisstar123 that's because you then call `normalizeWeights` after you add an iterm. I don't understand why you are surprised that other items get modified.

Comment: No, the item gets updated by the HashMap#put call in addBlocks (as i stated in my previous comment)

Comment: @chrisstar123 how did you determine that? Did you add some code directly before the `put()` and directly after the `put()` that prints out the contents of the map and compare the outputs?

Comment: i used a debugger

Comment: - Beware that hashmap overwrites the value if a key is same. 

- Use Map.containsKey() check before adding values if possible.

Comment: I just inserted few sysout before and after add. There is no change in DIRT value as you stated.  Log is :                                                   After adding iterating weightedBlocks to print values.

    ...Name: STONE; Data: 1; Weight:1.0

    ...Name: STONE; Data: 2; Weight:1.0

    ...Name: DIRT; Data: 1; Weight:1.0